# SpringBoot - Micrometer Composite Registry order changes behavior of /actuator/metrics/ page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I have three micrometer registries created as beans

```
0 = {InfluxMeterRegistry@7201} 
1 = {AutoConfiguredCompositeMeterRegistry@7339} 
2 = {PrometheusMeterRegistry@7330}
```

One of my classes gets injected with the @Primary MeterRegistry (AutoConfiguredCompositeMeterRegistry) . During operation of the application a counter is incremented like so

```
 Counter.builder("cmp.listener.dispatch.count")
      .tags(commonTags)
      .tag("success", "false")
      .description("Count off failed dispatch by event listener")
      .baseUnit("event")
      .tag("uri", uri)
      .register(meterRegistry).increment();
```

I noticed that the metrics do in-fact get published to their corresponding registries (influx, prometheus). However, on the actuator page /actuator/metrics/cmp.listener.dispatch.count
the counts get reset periodically, almost as if they behave like StepCounter not CumulativeCounter

Sometimes a change in the order of the micrometer registry beans    makes /actuator/metrics/cmp.listener.dispatch.count behave like a CumulativeCounter.

I am super confused - Order should not matter.
Where is the page /actuator/metrics/cmp.listener.dispatch.count getting its metrics from? What am I doing wrong.

Its almost as if InfluxMetricsRegistry wins and makes all counters StepCounters

Looking at the source for MetricEndpoint.java, it streams through the registries in CompositeMeterRegistry and finds the first metric that matches desired name. Which mean the order of Registries matter. However the order of registries is not deterministic since internally the CompositeMeterRegistry stores registries in the IdentityHashMap.

```
private volatile Set<CompositeMeterRegistry> parents = Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<>());
```

So if the MetricEndpoint find first a metric counter from the InfluxRegistry, /metrics endpoint Counters will behave like step counters. If it finds metric in the SimpleMetricRegistry it will behave like CumulativeCounter counter